# Calling a function when the datepicker closes, when I click only outside of the datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

Is it possible to set the datepicker to close only when I click outside the datepicker? When closing the calendar, if the date was selected, the `alertDate` function was called?

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-o8dm7y

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedDate: '',
      arrayDates: []
    };
  }

  handleChangeDate = (date) => {
    let newArrayDates = [...this.state.arrayDates]
    newArrayDates.push(date)

    this.setState({
      selectedDate: date,
      arrayDates: newArrayDates
    })
  }

  alertDate = () => {
    console.log(this.state.selectedDate)
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.arrayDates)
    return (
      <div>
         <DatePicker
            selected={this.state.selectedDate}
            onChange={this.handleChangeDate}
            showTimeSelect
            timeFormat="HH:mm"
            timeIntervals={15}
            dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
            timeCaption="time"
            placeholderText="Choose date..."
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution to your issues:

1. You can set `shouldCloseOnSelect` to `false` to close date picker only when its click outside.
2. For calling `alertDate` you can put it in `onBlur` callback.

Here is the sample example which would work for you:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    startDate: new Date()
  };

  handleChange = date => {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  };

  handleOnBlur = event => {
    const date = new Date(event.target.value);
    console.log(date);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <DatePicker
        key="example9"
        selected={this.state.startDate}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        shouldCloseOnSelect={false}
        onBlur={this.handleOnBlur}
        placeholderText="View blur callbacks in console"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!